# How to display asterisk for input password in C++ using CLion

Tags: c++, windows, passwords, codeblocks, clion

There is a lot of sample code online for a password program that hides the input with an asterisk. These programs work when I compile them with my CodeBlocks IDE by outputting a `*` everytime I type in a letter.

```
Enter Password  : ******
You entered : iiiiii
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 6.860 s
Press any key to continue.
```

However, when I use the CLion IDE, I can see the letters I type:

```
Enter Password  :iiiiii
 ******
You entered : iiiiii
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone explain why this difference exists between the two IDEs?

The code that I am using (I found it online) is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; //needed for cout and etc

int main()
{
    START:
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\nEnter Password  : ";
    char pass[32];//to store password.
    int i = 0;
    char a;//a Temp char
    for(i=0;;)//infinite loop
    {
        a=getch();//stores char typed in a
        if((a>='a'&&a<='z')||(a>='A'&&a<='Z')||(a>='0'&&a<='9'))
            //check if a is numeric or alphabet
        {
            pass[i]=a;//stores a in pass
            ++i;
            cout<<"*";
        }
        if(a=='\b'&&i>=1)//if user typed backspace
            //i should be greater than 1.
        {
            cout<<"\b \b";//rub the character behind the cursor.
            --i;
        }
        if(a=='\r')//if enter is pressed
        {
            pass[i]='\0';//null means end of string.
            break;//break the loop
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nYou entered : "<<pass;
    //here we can even check for minimum digits needed
    if(i<=5)
    {
        cout<<"\nMinimum 6 digits needed.\nEnter Again";
        getch();//It was not pausing :p
        goto START;
    }
    return 0;
}
//Lets check for errors.
//You can even put file system.
```

I know that there are a lot of questions similar to this one, however, none of them could explain why it is not working when using the CLion IDE.

Comment: You need to use something like [ncurse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: I've not actually used ncurse, @EdHeal, so how would I make the program with ncurse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
        s[i] = _getch(); _putch('*');
        if (s[i] == 13) break;
    };
    printf("\nYour pass is %s", s);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<conio.h>`, `_getch()` and `_putch()` are non-portable facilities found only in MS-DOS compilers.

Comment: @MikeKinghan They're also supported by Windows compilers, like Visual C++ and MinGW.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char pin[100];
    int k=0;
    cout<<"Enter  password : ";
    while(pin[k-1]!='\r') {
        pin[k]=getch();
        if(pin[k-1]!='\r') {
            cout<<"*";
        }
        k++;
    }
    pin[k-1]='\0';
    cout<<"\nYou entered : "<<pin<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i know this thread is a little old but use my implementation. It only accepts valid input (numbers and letter can be easily changed) and it supports backspace

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password = "";
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0x30; i < 0x5A; i++)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1)
            {
                if (i >= 0x41 && i <= 0x5A && ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 1) == 0 || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 1))
                    password += ((char)i + 32);
                else
                    password += (char)i;

                cout << "*";
                Sleep(50);
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BACK) & 1)
            {
                password.erase(password.size() - 1);
                system("cls");
                for (int i = 0; i < password.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout << '*';
                }
                Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << password;
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made some enhancement to Stilet code

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter login password:";
    char s[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10;i++) {
        s[i] = _getch();
        if (s[i] == 13) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            _putch('*');
        }
    };
    printf("\nYour pass is %s", s);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a cross-platform solution (or workaround maybe) as long as your platform supports `\b` and C++ 11. It does the following with two threads:

1. Thread A (`std::future<std::string>`): Listen to user input and return the next `std::getline`.
2. Thread B (the main thread): Wait until the listener returns. At the same time, it uses `\b* \b` rapidly enough (once per 10 ms in the following code) to effectively:

   - Erases the previous character, replacing it with `*`;
   - Erases the current character, in case of user deleting characters.

> Here is what it looks like:
>
> [image: An example of password inputting]
>
> However, it prints the first `*` before the user starts to input. Maybe using other placeholder characters, e.g. `█` (Unicode needed) is more intuitive to the user.

The `PasswordField` code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class PasswordField {
private:
  const std::string placeholder;
  const int precedings;
  const int trailers;

  void refreshPlaceholder() {
    for (int i = 0; i != precedings; ++i) {
      std::cout << '\b';
    }
    std::cout << placeholder;
    for (int i = 0; i != trailers; ++i) {
      std::cout << '\b';
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
  }

public:
  PasswordField(const std::string& placeholder, int precedingLength, int trailingLength)
  : placeholder(placeholder), precedings(precedingLength), trailers(trailingLength) {}

  std::string getline() {
    std::future<std::string> listener = std::async([]() {
      std::string answer;
      std::getline(std::cin, answer);
      return answer;
    });
    
    for (int i = 0; i != precedings; ++i) {
      std::cout << placeholder[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
    while (listener.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))
          != std::future_status::ready) {
      refreshPlaceholder();
    }
    return listener.get();
  }
};
```

You may use it like this:

```cpp
PasswordField field("* ", 1, 1);
std::cout << "Password: " << field.getline() << std::endl;

// or Unicode
PasswordField field("█ ", 1, 1);
std::cout << "Password: " << field.getline() << std::endl;

// or erasing all input (note that std::endl is needed)
PasswordField field(" ", 1, 1);
std::cout << "Password: " << std::endl << field.getline() << std::endl;

// or something complex
PasswordField field("* (Enter to confirm) ", 1, 20);
std::cout << "Password: " << field.getline() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password,P;
    char p;
    cout<<"Enter Password: ";
    p=_getch();
    while(p!=13)
    {
        if(p==8)
        {
            P.resize(P.length()-1);
            cout<<P;
            password.resize(password.length()-1);
        }
        else {
            P=P+"*";
            cout<<P;
            password.push_back(p);
        }
        p=_getch();
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Enter Password: ";
    }
    cout<<endl<<password<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Explain your solution and how it pertains to the question. Don't just dump code.

Answer (score 0):

sample program for password  protection from someone peeking in display while you type it...hope this may work for you.... any suggestion will be appreciated..

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void pass();  // function declaration 
void main()
 {
       clrscr();
       cout<<"enter password : ";
       pass();  // function call
       getch();

 }
```

```
void pass();
  {
    int i,x;
    char ch='/0',password[]="example",match[20];
    for(i=0;i>=0;)
     {
       ch=getch();

      if(ch!=8&&ch!=13)
        {
         cout<<"*";
         match[i]=ch;
         i++;
        }
      else if (ch==8) // if backspace is presssed
       {
         cout<<"\b \b"; // moves cursor to the left print <space> again move cursor to left
         i--;
       }
      else if(ch==13)
    {
         match[i]='\0'; // if enter is pressed, last character in match[] becomes null
        break;         // for end of string
    }
    else
    {
         break;
    }
  }
  if(strcmp(match,password)==0)// comparing two strings.. if equal returns 0
  {
   cout<<endl<<"password correct";
  }
  else
  {
   cout<<endl<<"wrong password"<<endl;
   puts(match);
  }
}
```